# Why is iTerm2's output staggered?

Tags: formatting, output, iterm2

This is a nightmare I've been plagued with for a while:

[image]

I have no idea what's causing it. I'm using iTerm2 (Build 3.0.10) and MiniTest, however I'm pretty sure this happens with other rake tests and some logging as well. I will try to update this question as I see it happen elsewhere.

EDIT: it happened on `bundle` output
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing this when I run anything in docker, and haven't got a handle on it at all.

Comment: A little light was shed by this: there is a difference between echo -e 'hello\nworld' and echo -e 'hello\n\rworld'. It implied that somewhere, a \r character was being ignored. For example, if I overrode my command prompt thusly: export PS1="\r\[\e[;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[m\]" (note the '\r' at the front), at least every new command would be placed correctly. However, the output is still staggered.

Comment: My issue was resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913851/why-is-iterm2s-output-staggered -- not sure if that's helpful, but thought it best to share